# MS Teams channel is hidden when created by MS Graph API request

Tags: php, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-api

I have problem, when I create MS team and channels using the MS Graph API, the channels are always hidden and users have to manually click show.

This is the request code to create MS team and two channels:

```
   $data = [
        'displayName' => 'Test MS Team',
        "template@odata.bind" => "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
        'description' => 'Created using MS Graph API v1',
        'channels' => [
            [
                'displayName' => 'Test channel 1',
                'isFavoriteByDefault' => true,
                'description' => 'Test channel 1 descriptions'
            ],
            [
                'displayName' => 'Test channel 2',
                'isFavoriteByDefault' => true,
                'description' => 'Test channel 2 descriptions'
            ]
        ],
        // Adding more than one member is currently not supported on MS graph
        'members' => [
            [
                '@odata.type' => '#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember',
                'roles' => ['owner'],
                'user@odata.bind' => "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('{$this->me()->getId()}')"
            ],
        ]
    ];

    $this->request('POST', '/teams', $data, [], true);
```

[MS Graph docs: Create a team with multiple channels, installed apps, and pinned tabs using delegated permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-create-a-team-with-multiple-channels-installed-apps-and-pinned-tabs-using-delegated-permissions)

And this is the results:

**Channels are hidden**

[image: MS Teams with hidden channels]

Comment: We have tested the below graph API and we are also getting same result. We are checking this internally; we will get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is controlled by

- [isFavoriteByDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/channel?view=graph-rest-1.0)

attribute on the channel, looks like this feature is currently not working and MS has created a bug for it please have a look over [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/17559)

Comment: We will keep you posted when there are any updates on this bug.